# Pointers and Strings relation

Tags: c, string, file, pointers, c-strings

I am trying to understand the relation between pointers and string by trial and test, I tried to run this program but, it got complied with no errros but when I enter the file

```
char *file_name;

printf("Enter the name of the file:");
gets(file_name);

printf("the file name is: %s",file_name);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: 1. `gets` has been removed from C 2. What do you think `file_name` points at?

Comment: Can you at least finish the question? That would at least make it look like you are making an effort to resolve the issue.

Comment: `by trial and test`. That's ok in itself but should not be instead of systematic learning via a reference resource such as a tutorial or book. These basic things would be covered in any such good resource and would save you asking Stackoverflow at every turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer

```
char *file_name;
```

is not initialized and has an indeterminate value. So the following statement

```
gets(file_name);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover the function `gets` is not a standard C function and it is unsafe.

What you need to do is to allocate a memory where you are going to read the file name and to use the standard C function `fgets` instead of gets.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//…

size_t n = 100;
char *file_name = malloc( n );

fgets( file_name, n, stdin );

file_name[ strcspn( file_name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

printf("the file name is: %s\n",file_name);

//…

free( file_name );

//...
```

This statement

```
file_name[ strcspn( file_name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

is required to exclude the new line character `'\n'` that can be appended to the entered string by the function `fgets`.